# How to use Makefile conditionals with bash commands as a preparation step for Makefile rules?

Tags: bash, makefile, conditional-statements

For some practical reasons, it would be useful for me to prepare the place for the Makefile rules in the working directory. Consider the hypothetical case that, if the `$(VAR)` value is true, I need to move the `test.f` file into the actual directory before compilation. I tried to use the `ifeq` conditional with the `mv` command, but it worked only when I closed it into a rule:

```
VAR=true

cond:
ifeq ($(VAR),true)
   @mv dir/test.f .
endif

test.x: test.o
   ifort -o test.x test.o

test.o: test.f
   ifort -c -o test.o test.f
```

In this case, however, only the `cond` rule is executed, but `test.x` and `test.o` not.
Is there any way that

```
ifeq ($(VAR),true)
     @mv dir/test.f .
endif
```

should be always executed without blocking the execution of (other) rules in the Makefile?

For completeness, I am enclosing the real conditional block which I would like to treat:

```
ifeq ($(VAR),"./")
  @if [ -d mod ]; then \
     mv mod/* .; \
     rm -rf mod; \
     fi
  @if [ -d gen ]; then \
     mv gen/* .; \
     rm -rf gen; \
   fi
  @if [ -d extra ]; then \
     mv extra/* .; \
     rm -rf extra; \
     fi
  @if [ -d lnk ]; then \
     mv lnk/* .; \
     rm -rf lnk; \
     fi
else
   @if [ ! -d mod ]; then \
      mkdir -p mod; \
      mv mod_*.f* mod; \
   fi
   @if [ ! -d txt ]; then \
      mkdir -p txt; \
      mv *.txt txt; \
   fi
   @if [ ! -d gen ]; then \
      mkdir -p gen; \
      mv *.f* gen; \
   fi
   @if [ ! -d lnk ]; then \
      mkdir -p lnk; \
      mv *.o lnk; \
      mv *.mod lnk; \
   fi
endif
```

Comment: Why not make a simple rule to copy the file, like `test.f: dir/test.f` `cp $< $@`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat We are talking about multiple actions in my real case. I need to move all (bunches of) files from directories `gen`, `mod`, and `txt`, after that remove these directories, and then start the execution of other rules. What is your suggestion in this case?

Comment: My first inclination is to suggest that you solve your problem at a higher level, by avoiding the need to perform all these moves in the first place.

Comment: In any case, shell commands cannot appear directly in a makefile, except inside a recipe.  Makefiles are not scripts, and you will start writing better ones as soon as you internalize that.

Comment: @John Bollinger, I would avoid this by using those files in their original places, but my collaborator would like to have all files in the CWD (while I don't want). For this purpose, I would like to have a trick to have them where the user wants (I massively hate all files vomited in the CWD).

Comment: So write an actual script that your collaborator can use to move the files.  Or if they are all generated files then provide something in the makefile to control where they are generated, instead of moving them around after the fact.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I guess that however professional makefile writer would be somebody, he cannot solve the problem of being files at a specific place and not their previous places without moving them into their desired place.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Unfortunately, what he wants to do is to enter `make`, nothing else. I would also want the same.

Comment: @RolandTóbiás, a professional would absolutely recognize the major issues associated with moving built files after they are built.  If you must, then provide a means to control where they are built, but wherever that is, *leave them there* until and unless they are outright removed (by a clean action, for example).  And FWIW, it is utterly conventional to build output files, especially object files and Fortran module files, alongside their corresponding sources.  If you don't like that then the best alternative is to provide for out of source building via `VPATH`.

Comment: @John Bollinger The main problem is that there are Fortran source files and precompiled object files which my collab wants to have in the CWD. These are dozens of files (especially the object files), but he always wants to check their timestamps and don't want to add the directory names to the command. This is one aspect. The other is the large set of files (even the number of source files is significant), which I don't want to see.

Comment: Precompiled object files sounds like a disaster waiting to happen, but overall, none of that seems particularly relevant.  If there are static resources whose location needs to be adjustable on a per-developer basis then we're back to a script, run at most once per dev, and then code in the makefile to instruct `make` where to find and / or where to put all relevant files.

Comment: @JohnBollinger The whole code which the Makefile is created for is a disaster already happened. It should be rewritten from scratch, but it it difficult to receive funding for this project in academic circles. Anyway, I really appreciate your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear, `make` is not a shell and makefiles are not shell scripts.  So you can't plop some shell scripting down anywhere in the makefile you want (whether it's prefixed with TAB or not) and have it work.  `make` can *invoke* a shell to run some shell scripting, but it will only do that for shell operations that appear in specific places.  Any text outside of those specific places, is considered makefile text (even if it's preceded by a TAB) and you'll get parser errors if it's not valid makefile syntax (which most shell scripting is not).

One place a shell script can appear is in the recipe of a rule (this is where it's indented with TAB: the TAB tells make which lines are part of the recipe and which are not).  The issue with this is that the recipe of a rule is only invoked if the target of the rule needs to be rebuilt.  There are various answers here which give some thoughts about how to do this.

The other place a shell script can appear (if you are using GNU Make) is in the `$(shell ..)` function.  So one option to solve your problem would be this:

```
VAR := true

ifeq ($(VAR),true)
 __dummy := $(shell mv dir/test.f .)
endif
```

The `__dummy` assignment is there just in case the shell script generates some output to stdout.

Of course if the script to be invoked is very complex it will be annoying to put it into a single invocation of `$(shell ...)` but it can be done: shell syntax is flexible enough for that.  Or you can use multiple invocations.  Or you can put all the commands into a separate shell script file and invoke that inside of `$(shell ...)`.

Ultimately I think that John's idea above where there's a separate operation that users need to invoke to "prep" the workspace is the best one.  This operation can be a makefile target like `make setup` then you have:

```
.PHONY: setup
setup:
        mv dir/file.f .
```

etc.  Be sure that `setup` is **not** the first target in the makefile and it will only be run if the user runs `make setup`.

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer. The `$(shell ...)` function seems to be well suited for my stupid task.